# Question with integration and derivatives.

Tags: integration, derivatives

If $f(x)=g(x)$,
then $\int \{\frac{d}{dx}f(x) \} dx = \int \{\frac{d}{dx}g(x) \} dx $

True or false?

Book answer : false.

---

I know that
If $f(x)=g(x)$,
then $\frac{d}{dx} \{\int f(x) dx \} = \frac{d}{dx} \{\int g(x) dx \} $  (It's true)

But
If $f(x)=g(x)$,
$\int \{\frac{d}{dx}f(x) \} dx = \int \{\frac{d}{dx}g(x) \} dx $ is really false?
Why?   I would like to hear your opinion.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that when you integrate a certain function there will always be an arbitrary constant in the end(to plus). For example, $f(x)= g(x)=x^2$, $\dfrac{d}{dx} f(x)=\dfrac{d}{dx} g(x)=2x$, but $\int \dfrac{d}{dx} f(x)dx=x^2+c_1$ and $\int \dfrac{d}{dx} g(x)dx=x^2+c_2$. Since $c_1$ and $c_2$ are not necessarily equal, $\int \dfrac{d}{dx} f(x)dx$ is not necessarily equal to $\int \dfrac{d}{dx} g(x)dx$.

Answer (score 1):

The problem for that second one is that in the process of integration, constants arise. (Remember that troubling $+C$?)

Okay so, the quoted statement means
$$f(x)=g(x)+C$$
instead of the intended $f(x)=g(x)$.

In the second statement, we are differentiating at last which eliminates the constants arosen due to the integration inside.

Hope this helps. Ask doubts if any :)